# Package conflict in meteor : Angular2 and Templating

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am in and out of a project with Meteor, trying to wrap my head around this framework (documentation is comparable to Ruby... just terrible and fragmented), and I get this error :

> While determining active plugins:
>   error: conflict: two packages included in the app (barbatus:angular2 and
>   templating) are both trying to handle *.html

And this is my installed packages :

```
autopublish               1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Publish the entire d...
blaze-html-templates      1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI wit...
ecmascript                0.1.5  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in al...
es5-shim                  4.1.13  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript ...
flemay:less-autoprefixer  1.1.0  The dynamic stylesheet language + Autoprefixer
insecure                  1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database w...
jquery                    1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-base               1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience         1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                     1.1.2  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo ove...
semantic:ui               2.1.4  Official Semantic UI Integration for Meteor
session                   1.1.1  Session variable
standard-minifiers        1.0.1  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by...
tracker                   1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
urigo:angular2-meteor     0.2.0+ Angular2 and Meteor integration
```

Now, I know that `barbatus:angular2` is used by `urigo:angular2-meteor`, but I'm unsure why it would conflict with `templating` (which is obviously required by something else... if not `meteor-base` itself.

How do I fix this?

#### ** Edit **

This is my *only* `.html` file :

```
<head>
  <title>larpdb</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

Basically, this is a brand new empty project; how can I avoid getting this error? Do I have to strictly not use `<template>` tags in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Meteor 1.2.0.2 you can use

```
> meteor remove blaze-html-templates

 Changes to your project's package version selections:

 blaze-html-templates   removed from your project
 caching-compiler       removed from your project
 caching-html-compiler  removed from your project
 templating             removed from your project
 templating-tools       removed from your project
```

Then add the urigo:angular2-meteor package (must download from GitHub)

```
 > meteor add urigo:angular2-meteor
```

Comment: Thanks! This does resolve the question, about the HTML package conflict. However starting tha app, it does no longer serve HTML and all I see is error 404.

Answer (score 1):

In meteor .html file have templates only. If you are creating angular templates and giving same extension then at that time it will throw error. because in meteor only master file have html tag and if you adding different html file not having template tag then it will treat it as HTML file and add html tag in it while building.

so if you are creating templates for angular just rename it somefile.ng.html.
so that while meteor build it will don't have conflict.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, now I updated my question because I don't think it resolves my problem.

Comment: where you put it under client folder ?? Please follow folder structure of meteor. are you recently  updated you meteor version ?
can you please share the repository ? it would easy to find he cause.

Comment: What does the folder structure have to do with this? The `index.html` file was in the project root. I tried to put it inside `client` but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: folder changes because it would help you in loading js accordingly. if you put client side js in client folder and server side js in server folder there might be chance of js loading issue in your case. please remove angular2 and install urigo:angular.

Answer (score 0):

> meteor remove blaze-html-templates
>
> meteor remove ecmascript

Run the following commands to remove meteor's default ecmascript package .
Now the app should run fine .